# What does raspi-config do when you enable i2c?

Tags: i2c, raspi-config

Is there any documentation for the raspi-config command that would explain what it actually does when enabling i2c?

In the past I have just removed the i2c blacklist, added the modules and made sure the Pi user was in the correct group, reboot and i2c has created the /dev nodes.

But on a new Pi (Raspbian/B+) I could not get it to work until I followed the Advanced option in raspi-config and enbaled i2c there(and rebooted).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> But on a new Pi (Raspbian/B+) I could not get it to work until I followed the Advanced option in raspi-config and enbaled i2c there(and rebooted).

This is because newer Raspbian kernels use [device tree](http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/device-tree.md) "to manage some resource allocation and module loading":

> The main impact of using Device Tree is to change from *everything on*, relying on module blacklisting to manage contention, to *everything off unless requested*...

`Raspi-config` is a shell script in `/usr/bin` on Raspbian.  In the version I'm looking at from a 2015-01-31 image, the "Advanced Option":

> Enable/Disable automatic loading of I2C kernel module

Does a couple of things:

- 1. It checks `/boot/config.txt` for an uncommented line beginning w/ `device_tree_param=` or `dtparam=`.  If it does not find one, it asks,

  > Would you like the ARM I2C interface to be enabled?
  If you do, it adds
  `dtparam=i2c_arm=on`
  to the end of
  `/boot/config.txt`
  .
- 2. It then looks for an `/etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf`, which does not exist by default.  If it doesn't exist, it creates it, but leaves it empty. Then it asks,

  > Would you like the I2C kernel module to be loaded by default?
  If you do, it runs
  `modprobe i2c-bcm2708`
  (i.e., loads the module) and deletes any line in that
  `raspi-blacklist.conf`
  file beginning with
  `blacklist`
  and
  `i2c-bcm2708`
  or
  `i2c_bcm2708`
  .
  If you don't, it adds `blacklist i2c-bcm2708` to the end of that file if such a line doesn't exist.

Older versions of the script would not have had step #1 because it was not required with older kernels.  The i2c module would have been loaded by default, so "enabling" it was just a matter of making sure it wasn't previously blacklisted.  Newer versions of the kernel require a line be added to `config.txt`; you would have to reboot to make this effective.

Comment: That is a seriously complete answer. Thanks for your time, this was exactly what I was looking for.